# Windows 10 IoT Core remove WiFi profile programatically

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I need to remove a saved wifi profilefrom code, so that the SoftAP is enabled again. According to the ms docs, there is no way to remove a profile, only disconnect. Is this not possible?

Ms docs for wifi
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifi.wifiadapter

Device Portal API
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-ch/windows/mixed-reality/device-portal-api-reference#wifi-management

Here is my working code for disconnecting from a wifi using device portal API

```
        // API creds
        string username = "Administrator";
        string password = "p@ssw0rd

        // API request URIs
        string apiUri = "http://192.168.1.15:8080/api/wifi/network";

        // WiFi details
        string wifiInterface = string.Empty;
        string wifiProfile = string.Empty;

        // WiFi access
        WiFiAccessStatus wifiAccess = await WiFiAdapter.RequestAccessAsync();

        if (wifiAccess == WiFiAccessStatus.Allowed)
        {
            // Get WiFi adapter
            IReadOnlyList<WiFiAdapter> wifiAdapterResult = await WiFiAdapter.FindAllAdaptersAsync();
            WiFiAdapter wifiAdapter = wifiAdapterResult[0];

            // Get conn profile / details
            ConnectionProfile profile = await wifiAdapter.NetworkAdapter.GetConnectedProfileAsync();
            wifiInterface = profile.NetworkAdapter.NetworkAdapterId.ToString();
            wifiProfile = profile.ProfileName;
        }

        // API creds
        PasswordCredential credentials = new PasswordCredential("login", username, password);

        // HttpClient filter
        HttpBaseProtocolFilter filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
        filter.CookieUsageBehavior = HttpCookieUsageBehavior.NoCookies;
        filter.CacheControl.ReadBehavior = HttpCacheReadBehavior.MostRecent;
        filter.CacheControl.WriteBehavior = HttpCacheWriteBehavior.NoCache;
        filter.ServerCredential = credentials;

        // HttpClient
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(filter);

        apiUri = apiUri + "?interface=" + wifiInterface + "&op=disconnect" + "&createprofile=no";

        // Request
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        request.Method = new HttpMethod("POST");
        request.RequestUri = new Uri(apiUri);

        // Send request
        try
        {
            // Response
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendRequestAsync(request);

            // Again
            if (response.Content.ToString().Contains("Authorization Required"))
            {
                response = await client.SendRequestAsync(request);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Dispose
            client.Dispose();
            filter.Dispose();
        }
```

But for deleting a wifi profile, i get 404 not found back from the API. According to the API docs linked above, the request should be ok. Here is my code for deleting a wifi profile

```
        // API creds
        string username = "Administrator";
        string password = "p@ssw0rd

        // API request URIs
        string apiUri = "http://192.168.1.15:8080/api/wifi/network";

        // WiFi details
        string wifiInterface = string.Empty;
        string wifiProfile = string.Empty;

        // WiFi access
        WiFiAccessStatus wifiAccess = await WiFiAdapter.RequestAccessAsync();

        if (wifiAccess == WiFiAccessStatus.Allowed)
        {
            // Get WiFi adapter
            IReadOnlyList<WiFiAdapter> wifiAdapterResult = await WiFiAdapter.FindAllAdaptersAsync();
            WiFiAdapter wifiAdapter = wifiAdapterResult[0];

            // Get conn profile / details
            ConnectionProfile profile = await wifiAdapter.NetworkAdapter.GetConnectedProfileAsync();
            wifiInterface = profile.NetworkAdapter.NetworkAdapterId.ToString();
            wifiProfile = profile.ProfileName;
        }

        // API creds
        PasswordCredential credentials = new PasswordCredential("login", username, password);

        // HttpClient filter
        HttpBaseProtocolFilter filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
        filter.CookieUsageBehavior = HttpCookieUsageBehavior.NoCookies;
        filter.CacheControl.ReadBehavior = HttpCacheReadBehavior.MostRecent;
        filter.CacheControl.WriteBehavior = HttpCacheWriteBehavior.NoCache;
        filter.ServerCredential = credentials;

        // HttpClient
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(filter);

        apiUri = apiUri + "?interface=" + wifiInterface + "&profile=" + wifiProfile;

        // Request
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        request.Method = new HttpMethod("DELETE")
        request.RequestUri = new Uri(apiUri);

        // Send request
        try
        {
            // Response
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendRequestAsync(request);

            // Again
            if (response.Content.ToString().Contains("Authorization Required"))
            {
                response = await client.SendRequestAsync(request);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Dispose
            client.Dispose();
            filter.Dispose();
        }
```

Edit//

To close this problem, since build 17763, there is a new method for deleting WiFi profiles directly from code available

```
bool canDelete = wifiProfile.CanDelete;
if (canDelete)
{
     ConnectionProfileDeleteStatus deleteStatus = await wifiProfile.TryDeleteAsync();
}
```

Comment: first off, you need to show us some code with what you have tried to do and what your result is. 

Also, can you reference the MS article that you have mentioned too. Its entirely possible that its not possible to remove a profile via code, but then again theres usually always a way to do something. You just have to invest some time and trial and error

Comment: I have added a link to the ms docs for wifi control. There is no such method for deleting a profile. I have no code to show, because i have not found something like that.

Comment: can you show us your code too

Comment: Currently i have no code, because i couldn't find any API or method for deleting a wifi profile. The only thing which I have found is the Windows Device Portal API, but there are no examples, so I don't know exactly how to use. I have edited the link in to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately without anything for us to work with with what you want, there is nothing we can do.  If you had some code example on how you were pulling it in, and had attempted something to remove the device we could possibly do something to help you.

Comment: On the second link I provided in the question, there seems to be a way for deleting a wifi profile, but I don't know how to call this API with these parameters from code?

Comment: No i have added some code after a few hours of testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this problem, since build 17763, there is a new method for deleting WiFi profiles directly from code available

```
bool canDelete = wifiProfile.CanDelete;
if (canDelete)
{
     ConnectionProfileDeleteStatus deleteStatus = await wifiProfile.TryDeleteAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to call `netsh` from your program.

`netsh wlan delete <profile name>` should get you there.

Comment: As far as i know does this require to add a reg key, so this is no option for me.

Comment: Add a reg key for what?  To spawn a process?  I don't think so.  `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` will launch `netsh` for you.

Comment: I read on the msdn forums from a user, that it requires to add a reg key for launching a system command. With using of the devive portal api, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

After trying for hours, finally found a solution! For those who are interested, you have to call the "run command" API, which allows you to run certain windows commands

```
string deleteCommand = "netsh wlan delete profile name=*";

string cmdApi = string.Format("http://192.168.1.15:8080/api/iot/processmanagement/runcommand?command={0}&runasdefaultaccount={1}", GetBase64String(deleteCommand), GetBase64String("no"));
```

The really important thing to note here is that you have to encode the command as a base64 string, otherwise it won't work!

```
private string GetBase64String(string stringToConvert)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToConvert));
}
```

With this code, it is finally possible for me to delete either certain wifi profiles, or in the example case above, every saved profile.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Andy for finding this. I was doing it with command line before but this does work. I added some supporting code around it to help others where I had some issues such as get, delete or post. If it works then I restart IoT to be back in Onboarding mode. Maybe someone will find this helpful.

Logging into the portal as admin may or may not be required but that is how I do it. The if (interfaceGUID != null) was assigned by a previous Api request and can be removed for testing.

```
private string password = "yourpassword";
private string localhost = "127.0.0.1";                              
private async Task DeleteProfile()
    {
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                if (interfaceGUID != null)
                {
                    string deleteCommand = "netsh wlan delete profile name=*";
                    using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, string.Format("http://{0}:8080/api/iot/processmanagement/runcommand?command={1}&runasdefaultaccount={2}", localhost, Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(deleteCommand)), Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("no")))))
                    {
                        request.Headers.Authorization = CreateBasicCredentials("Administrator");
                        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request))
                        {
                            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode == true)
                            {
                                 ShutdownManager.BeginShutdown(Windows.System.ShutdownKind.Restart, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine("Could not delete the profiles. " + response.ReasonPhrase.ToString());
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                client.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Could not delete the profiles. " + ex.InnerException.ToString());
        }
    }
private AuthenticationHeaderValue CreateBasicCredentials(string userName)
    {
        string toEncode = userName + ":" + password;
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
        byte[] toBase64 = encoding.GetBytes(toEncode);
        string parameter = Convert.ToBase64String(toBase64);
        return new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", parameter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Been working on Windows device portal API recently and came across this post.  The reason your code got 404 response is because in the API URI, the `&profile=` expects a Base64 value instead of a text string that you're using.  Once you encode the profile name to Base64, it should work.

I believe this isn't explicitly stated in MS's device portal documentation, as I only discovered this by using web browser debugger to inspect Windows Device Portal web page when deleting a WIFI profile.